# Is it possible to be a Linux professional studying on your own?

Tags: linux

I read economics at university(nothing to see with linux, isn't it? :P). 
I have some basic knowledge about booting process, Linux Kernel compiling from source and stuff like that.
But of course I have still much to learn sometimes some errors appears and "voila" I am lost.
I had: Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSuse, Arch.. using Gentoo now.

I'd like to know what you linux users, professionals, administrators... would think it is the best way to learn linux in a professional way.
Is it worth studying it and passing the LPIC test enough to work in the linux world? or do I need going to IT uni?
I've heard LFS is a good way of learning about linux, is that real?
I've been thinking about getting to LFS learn about more deeply about the linux process and learning scripts.

It is possible to do this way? if anyone has a tip or a good way of doing, maybe someone did it. Any tip is very welcome.

Words from a person in love with linux. :D

The best,
Marc

Comment: this is really something that should be posted to a discussion forum.  Slashdot or Ubuntu Forums come to mind as appropriate venues for this question.  Super User is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. One thing I love about the IT industry is that you don't need a university degree to get jobs, there are industry-specific certifications that you can get to show you know what you're doing (CCNA, MCDBA etc).

As far as learning about Linux to become a professional, take a look [here](http://www.gocertify.com/faq/linuxfaq.shtml). Find the relevant training material for those certifications and learn as much as you can.

Do that in between exploring on your own and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to learn is to deal with other people. Certification exams tend to be artificial in that the question is obvious. When you sit down and have to deal with someone who doesn't really understand the system and has a problem you need to diagnose.

Many universities have opportunities for students to volunteer or be paid to assist students. Even if this is for Windows it would still be valuable experience that would help you in the real world.

Comment: I agree with you the solving problems is very helpfull in the learning process. I've been getting some things done.. but I miss practice resources. exercises would be very good. I just can't find a ressource with plenty of practical exercices, you now? getting the hands dirty is very usefull for me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Best people involve in GNU/Linux are self made and self taught.. so why you be different man?
As with this age of internet helps people to come together to share invaluable information...tap it..connect with right guy.

Al the best to your GNU/Linux learning.

Cheers mate!